# Hello, I should use floor function in cplex , but it does not work. I is a decision variable and J is a constant

Tags: math, cplex, modeling

sum(f in Nuflow) floor (sum(v in Nuvnf, n in Nunode, j in Nusfc) I[v] [n] [f] [j]/J)

---

```
//ranges
int N=11;
range Nunode=0..N;
int V=5;
range Nuvnf=1..V;
int J=5;
range Nusfc=1..J;
int F=50;
range Nuflow =1..F;

//decision variable
dvar boolean I[Nuvnf][Nunode][Nuflow][Nusfc];
dexpr float x[f in Nuflow]=sum(v in Nuvnf, n in Nunode, j in Nusfc) I [v][n][f][j] / J;
float y[f in Nuflow];

maximize sum(f in Nuflow) y[f];

subject to {forall(f in Nuflow, j in Nusfc) cons:sum(n in Nunode, v in Nuvnf) I[v][n][f][j] <= 1;}

execute {writeln(x, "x==>y", y);}

assert forall(f in Nuflow) y[f]==floor(x[f]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I put new code in my main code. I did not have error. scripting and solution of parts didn't show anything. Just my code is running for 2 hours and it didn't stop.I paused it myself. What's your opinion? What should I do? Thank a million.

Answer (score 0):

you should linearize floor.

See [floor example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/floor.mod) in [How to with OPL CPLEX](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/) ?

```
    range r=1..4;

    float x[r]=[1.5,4.0,2.0001,5.9999];

    dvar int y[r];
    dvar float f[r] in 0..0.99999;

    subject to
    {
    forall(i in r) x[i]==y[i]+f[i];


    }

    execute
    {
    writeln(x," ==> ",y);
    }

    assert forall(i in r) y[i]==floor(x[i]);
```

//which gives

//    [1.5 4 2.0001 5.9999] ==>  [1 4 2 5]

and with your code that gives

```
//ranges
int N=11;
range Nunode=0..N;
int V=5;
range Nuvnf=1..V;
int J=5;
range Nusfc=1..J;
int F=50;
range Nuflow =1..F;

//decision variable
dvar boolean I[Nuvnf][Nunode][Nuflow][Nusfc];
dexpr float x[f in Nuflow]=sum(v in Nuvnf, n in Nunode, j in Nusfc) I [v][n][f][j] / J;
dvar int y[f in Nuflow];
dvar float f[i in Nuflow] in 0..0.99999;

maximize sum(f in Nuflow) y[f];

subject to {forall(f in Nuflow, j in Nusfc) cons:sum(n in Nunode, v in Nuvnf) I[v][n][f][j] <= 1;

forall(i in Nuflow) x[i]==y[i]+f[i];

x[1]==0.2;
}

execute {writeln(x, "x==>y", y);}

assert forall(f in Nuflow) y[f]==floor(x[f]);
```

that gives

```
// solution (optimal) with objective 49
 [0.2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]x==>y [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your example on my code. But I got zero. Is it true or false? I will send my code.